# Returning an integer array pointer in C

Tags: c

I am trying to return a pointer to an array of integers representing the result of applying each function in the array to value n.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*funT)(int);
int *mapApply(int n, funT fs[], int size);
int func1(int);
int func2(int);
int func3(int);
int func4(int);
int func5(int);

int main() {

    funT array[5] = { func1, func2, func3, func4, func5 };
    mapApply(2, array, 5 );

    return 0;
}

int func1 (int n) {
    return n + 1;
}

int func2 (int n) {
    return n + 2;
}

int func3 (int n) {
    return n + 3;
}

int func4 (int n) {
    return n + 4;
}

int func5 (int n) {
    return n + 5;
}

int *mapApply(int n, funT fs[], int size) {
    int result[size] = { fs[0](n), fs[1](n), fs[2](n), fs[3](n), fs[4](n) };
    return &result;
}
```

Currently my mapApply function isn't working. Here is the compilation error:

> prog.c: In function ‘mapApply’: prog.c:41:2: error: variable-sized
>   object may not be initialized   int result[size] = { fs0,
>   fs1, fs2, fs3, fs4 };   ^ prog.c:41:2: warning:
>   excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default] prog.c:41:2:
>   warning: (near initialization for ‘result’) [enabled by default]
>   prog.c:41:2: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by
>   default] prog.c:41:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘result’)
>   [enabled by default] prog.c:41:2: warning: excess elements in array
>   initializer [enabled by default] prog.c:41:2: warning: (near
>   initialization for ‘result’) [enabled by default] prog.c:41:2:
>   warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
>   prog.c:41:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘result’) [enabled by
>   default] prog.c:41:2: warning: excess elements in array initializer
>   [enabled by default] prog.c:41:2: warning: (near initialization for
>   ‘result’) [enabled by default] prog.c:42:2: warning: return from
>   incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]   return &result;   ^
>   prog.c:42:2: warning: function returns address of local variable
>   [-Wreturn-local-addr]

Comment: You realise that `result` goes out of scope when the function returns, and is thus unusable?

Comment: I see, how do would i return a useable array, so i could say print out the contents in the main method?

Comment: Or pass a pointer to an arrays which the function will fill. C's way of doing output parameters.

Comment: Malloc the array and return a pointer to the dynamically allocated memory.   Or, pass a pointer to an array into the function and have the function fill/initialize it.

Comment: It is not possible to write an initialization list in the VLA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this

```
int *mapApply(int n, funT fs[], int size) {
    int result[size] = { fs[0](n), fs[1](n), fs[2](n), fs[3](n), fs[4](n) };
    return &result;
}
```

you have two errors:

- A pointer to `result` is incompatible to the return type of `mapApply`, and
- You are trying to return a pointer to a local array.

To fix this, you need to allocate the array dynamically, or pass a buffer into the function. Here is how you allocate the array dynamically:

```
int *mapApply(int n, funT fs[], int size) {
    int *result = malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
        result[i] = fs[i](n);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The caller needs to `free` the result of the call of `manApply` in order to avoid a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Variable length arrays cannot be initialised using an initialiser list.

Doing this

```
size_t s = 4;
int a[s] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

is not valid C.